# Preventing <a> from self closing within conditional

Tags: craft3

When an `<a>` is used within a conditional, the output of the `<a>` adds a self-closing a `</a>`. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I didn't realize this occurred.

```
{% if true %}
    <a href="#">
{% endif %}

EXPECTED OUTPUT: <a href="#">
ACTUAL OUTPUT: <a href="#"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in Craft core that would cause this.

Have you inspected the actual rendered HTML source, or are you looking at it in your browser's dev tools' DOM/elements panel? Typically, browsers will do their best to (auto)correct obvious HTML errors (like an unclosed tag).

Comment: You nailed it. Had no idea DevTools did that, especially because the source code shows the closing tags. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The browser will always try to close unclosed tags, that's the point.

You can change your output logic to like this, but that's really a bad way:

```
  {% set condition = true %}
  {% set html = '' %}
  {% if condition %}
    {% set html = '<a href="#">My link' %}
  {% endif %}
  {# ... #}
  {% if condition %}
    {% set html = html ~ '</a>' %}
   {% endif %}
  {{ html|raw }}
```

You must change the logic so that you do not use such "crutches"

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered, but I think I can guess what you're trying to do and there's a much cleaner way. Try something like this:

```
{% set innards %}
    <h3>Lots of lengthy markup here</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p>etc</p>
{% endset %}

{% if condition %}
    <a href="{{ thing.url }}">{{ innards|raw }}</a>
{% else %}
    {{ innards }}
{% endif %}
```

This is similar to Roman's answer above, but I prefer this way a bit using set...endset as you don't need to worry so much about escaping characters.

Comment: That's a great solution. Thanks!